# How to change woocommerce category id?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change category id in woocommerce table.
Example: change id=5 to id=20.
I don't want to delete my categories in my wordpress panel, just change that id from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just go to phpmyadmin and change it?

This of course can cause conflicting issues if id=20 is already assigned and its not what you want

Comment: @AliRasouli, It's more complex than that as there is multiple tables involved: wp_terms, wp_termmeta, wp_term_taxonomy and wp_term_relationships… You will need to change the related ID for term_id and term_taxonomy_id columns on all related tables…